# Predictive always prompt error

Tags: predictive-mode

When using predictive-mode, the following error often pops up:

> Error running timer `completion-ui-auto-show': (error "Keyword argument :face not one of (:point :around :width :height :min-height :max-width :truncate :margin :margin-left :margin-right :scroll-bar :parent :parent-offset :nowait :nostrip :prompt)")

I removed all other extensions, removed custom Emacs settings and only left predictive mode turned on, this problem still persists. What can I do about it?

**EDIT** It turned out that predictive mode also includes a "popup.el" itself, while I also installed the auto-complete popup.el, which conflict with each other. Is there any way to resolve the conflict?

Comment: Hand in a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by predictive which uses its shipped popup.el which conflicts with the popup.el in ac-mode if you have installed.

The following bash script would patch predictive and resolve the conflict.

```
for f in *.el; do sed -i -r 's/([ \t('"'"']+)popup/\1mypredictive-popup/g' $f; done
sed -i 's/make-popup/make-mypredictive-popup/g' popup.el
mv popup.el mypredictive-popup.el
```